# How can I create a separate blog that is private?

Tags: login, private

I am very new at all this and not a programmer. I want to know how to set up a private blog that requires a member login to view it. Is there a widget that one may suggest that does this.

I am using the Unite theme and the site I am trying to put together is at [tmpfire.com](http://tmpfire.com). I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: I'm working on a separate, second blog for logged-in users, and I'm using is a number of plugins: Login With Ajax, TDO Mini Forms (providing forms for logged-in users to post drafts with, that the admin then can moderate, or have them post straight away), and Role Scoper (to restrict access to that blog's categories). I've also defined a taxonomy for tags to be used in that separate blog. I've hacked the TDO Mini Forms plugin to only add tags from that taxonomy to posts. And I think I have got it: a simple forum-like solution within WP itself. Would you like code examples?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can set up a separate, private blog that requires members to log in.  You can do this with a plug-in called [Members Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/) - it's freely available from the WordPress plug-in repository.

Anyone who visits the site who's not logged in will be directed automatically to the login screen.  After users log in, they can browse the site normally.

---

#### Edit 12/15/10

Based on your comments, it sounds like you don't need a private blog - you need a private bulletin board or forum.

I would recommend setting up a system like [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) in a sub-folder on the site (i.e. http://tmpfire.com/forum/) and installing bbPress in that folder.  You can incorporate bbPress with WordPress, or keep it entirely separate.  But you can also keep it private.

This way, you can have a WordPress-powered website with a private information/discussion board for members only.

Comment: Would this control the home page blog for I am looking to setup a separate blog and control that one?

Comment: You said you wanted to set up a separate blog - so you'd create a second blog (**not** the main site) and install the plug-in on that one.

Comment: I am lost due I do not understand what you trying to tell me, sorry

Comment: You currently have one website (tmpfire.com) which is running on WordPress.  Do you want your private blog to be a separate website?  Or do you want your private blog to be a part of tmpfire.com?  If you want it to be a part of tmpfire.com, how will it fit into the existing public website?

Comment: I do not wish to have a separate website I wish it to be apart of the same website. I wish it to be for the department to discus various topics something like this on http://www.slofiretraining.org/bbs/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me and your all your help

Comment: Will ddPress ask you where you wish to install it? How would I go about setting up the location you suggested and getting it installed to that location?

Comment: You'll need to create a sub-folder on your website - basically put a `forums` folder alongside `wp-content`, `wp-admin`, and `wp-includes` on your site.  Then put all of the bbPress files in there.  You'll also want to set up a second MySQL database to support the forums. Full installation instructions are on the [bbPress website](http://bbpress.org/documentation/installation/).